# Append html to .text() method at D3 library

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Please help get to work that `< br/ >` tag at `.text()` method in D3 library.
That's what I have tried at this moment. Obviously it show me simple text, even br tag.

```
var text_box = g
    .selectAll(".text-box")
    .data(function(d) { return points.slice(2, d); })
    .enter()
    .append("text")
    .attr({
        "class": "text-box",
        "dx": x,
        "dy": y,
        "transform": "translate(" + 15 + "," + 5 + ")"
    })
    .text(function(d, i) { return count+" changed <br/> by @"+name});
```

I have even tried to append `div` tag and used `.html()` method, but that was not going to work too. What I did wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SVG `<text>` elements do not support line breaks directly. From [the specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/text.html#Introduction):

> Each ‘text’ element causes a single string of text to be rendered. SVG performs no automatic line breaking or word wrapping. To achieve the effect of multiple lines of text, use one of the following methods:
>
> - The author or authoring package needs to pre-compute the line breaks and use multiple ‘text’ elements (one for each line of text).
> - The author or authoring package needs to pre-compute the line breaks and use a single ‘text’ element with one or more ‘tspan’ child elements with appropriate values for attributes ‘x’, ‘y’, ‘dx’ and ‘dy’ to set new start positions for those characters which start new lines. (This approach allows user text selection across multiple lines of text -- see Text selection and clipboard operations.)
> - Express the text to be rendered in another XML namespace such as XHTML [XHTML] embedded inline within a ‘foreignObject’ element. (Note: the exact semantics of this approach are not completely defined at this time.)

I don't think `<div>` elements work inside SVG either.

An example of the second approach is here: http://jsfiddle.net/eVmsW/

Comment: so.. is it possible to move to a new line? that's all what I need

Comment: Yes, it is possible and there are three ways of doing it. :) I have included an example of one of the ways in the answer now.